# how to list of all models and include one common module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm working on a Rails 3 app. I wrote one module and want it accessible to all my models without using `include` in each one. Please help me do this.

Answer (score 3):

Create a file `config/initializers/your_module_name.rb`:

```
class ActiveRecord::Base
  include YourModule
end
```